# History log in sub directory

Tags: libgit2sharp

I'm trying to figure out how to get the commit log for a sub directory.  According to [this thread](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/963), it should work fine in libgit2sharp.

For testing I'm using a small repo, https://github.com/ornatwork/nugetpackages.git that has 8 total entries for the whole repository.

I cloned it locally in root c:/nugetpackages, from that folder I can do.
git log -- devbox
on the command line and I will get two commit entries for the /devbox sub directory as expected.

Sample Xunit test code to do the same using libgit2sharp

```
  [Fact]
  public void testSub()
  {
    // Extract the git commit history
    using (var repo = new Repository(@"C:\nugetpackages"))
    {
      Trace.WriteLine("repo count=" + repo.Commits.Count());
      // absolute path
      IEnumerable<LogEntry> history = repo.Commits.QueryBy(@"C:\nugetpackages\devbox");
      Trace.WriteLine("subdir count=" + history.Count());
    }
  }
```

I'm expecting count of 8 and 2, but this is what I get.
repo count=8
subdir count=0

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a relative path from the repository's base diretory:

```
using (var repo = new Repository(@"/Users/sushi/code/sushi/Xamarin.Forms.Renderer.Tests"))
{
    D.WriteLine("repo count=" + repo.Commits.Count());
    IEnumerable<LogEntry> history = repo.Commits.QueryBy(@"AlarmSO");
    D.WriteLine("subdir count=" + history.Count());
}
```

ref: [FileHistoryFixture.cs](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/master/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/FileHistoryFixture.cs)

#### Update:

> Follow up, is there a way to combine subdir with a filter, for example. CommitFilter filter = new CommitFilter(); filter.FirstParentOnly = true;

Not sure if this is what you are looking for... if not please in a new question, thanks.

```
using (var repo = new Repository(@"/Users/sushi/code/sushi/RealmJson"))
{
    var subDir = "media";
    var commits = repo.Commits.QueryBy(new CommitFilter { FirstParentOnly = true }).Where(
                     (Commit c) => c.Tree.Any(
                        (TreeEntry te) => te.Path.StartsWith(subDir, StringComparison.Ordinal)));
    foreach (var commit in commits)
    {
        D.WriteLine($"{commit.Sha} : {commit.MessageShort}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thnx.  Follow up, is there a way to combine subdir with a filter, for example.          CommitFilter filter = new CommitFilter();
        filter.FirstParentOnly = true;

Comment: @OrnKristjansson Are you looking for the merge commit (first parent) that added/changed something in a specific directory?

Comment: Yes, lets say I'm on master, I only want to see commits to master, and exclude whatever was done on branch before merging in.  For root I can do this, foreach ( Commit commit in repo.Commits.QueryBy(filter)).  How can I do that when I'm getting commits for a sub directory.

Comment: @OrnKristjansson I updated my answer... Not sure if this is what you are looking for... if not. please post a new question...